# Can I use plastic sheeting in a storage attic to contain blown insulation?

Tags: attic, studs, plastic

I have a 21 foot x 21 foot attached garage with an attic above for storage. There are supporting studs that are about 5-1/2 feet in from each side (so 10’ between studs. There is blown in insulation with 3/4” plywood between the studs. The 5-1/2 feet on either side just blown in insulation.

Is there any issue attaching plastic sheeting from the floor to about 5 feet up to keep the insulation from getting onto the floor when moving stuff around up there? Insulation is only above the drywall ceiling of the garage. No insulation between vertical supporting studs I want to attach plastic to. This would leave over a foot open above the plastic to the underside of the roof.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Comment: How deep is the insulation? Coming up 5 feet seems like a lot more than would be needed, even if it was 1.5-2 feet deep in that part. (Which would, in fact, be helpful, as it's more than half the ceiling area - can't do much to increase insulation where the floor is, but outside it, more is better.)

Comment: It would also act to prevent things from falling into the insulation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue using sheeting that way as long as it doesn't encapsulate air where it can trap moisture. That doesn't seem to be the case here.

I would suggest something other than common polyethylene sheeting, though, as it tends to get torn up over time. Consider rigid panels of some sort, or at least a reinforced sheeting like ripstop tarp material or house wrap.

Comment: Some of the pink foam sheets could work here, or even corrugated plastic sheets (Coroplast).